# Links in a fixed element don't work when overflow hidden

Tags: css, scroll, menu, overflow, fixed

Here is my simplified problem :      https://jsfiddle.net/44sjaq1q/2

I use a fixed bottom menu hidden with `z-index:-1` `position:fixed`, and revealed with the scroll. But, the links in the menu don't work.

In my page, I use elements creating a x-scrolling, but i use a `overflow-x: hidden`, to unabled the horizontal movement.

It seems the two rules can't work in the same time.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's because of `z-index:-1`. Negative z-index send the elements to back, hence they are not accessible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of `z-index:-1`. Negative z-index send the elements to back, hence they are not accessible.

Remove `z-index: -1` and the links will be accessible. [**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Pugazh/44sjaq1q/3/)

Comment: Thank you , I used z-index:0 for the menu and z-index:1 for the other sections